# Chrome Management API

Tags: google-api, google-workspace, google-apis-explorer, chromebook

I'm trying to use the Chrome Management API from the API EXPLORER but I can't get the CUSTOMER_ID I tried to use "my_customer" or the Customer ID from my adminconsole and it doesn't recognize it.

Does anyone know what identifier it refers to?

Annex screenshots

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The pattern that you need to add in the customer field section is:

customers/customerID

Example:
customers/Ex123abc

You can get your [Customer ID](https://support.google.com/a/answer/10070793) in the Google Workspace Admin console by going to Admin console > Account > Account settings > Profile > Customer ID.

Reference below:

[Sample image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vdCtt.png)

Comment: If this answers your question, please click the accept button on the left (check icon) and upvoting the answer.  By doing so, other people in the community, who may have the same concern as you, will know that theirs can be resolved.  If the accept button is unavailable to you, feel free to tell me.